# SQL Server Querying Catalog to View DDL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

In SSMS, I cannot view the DDL of a view by clicking on the object explorer.

I do have access to the catalog though.

Is there anyway to query the catalog to retrieve a views ddl? Does anyone have any other suggestions than to ask for the correct access?

I'm trying to finish something for work and nobody will be able to give me access until Monday.

Edit: Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('schema.view_name')) AS ObjectDefinition;   
GO
```

This did not work because the view has encryption status.

Comment: Your code is OK - but since the view in **encrypted** you **CANNOT** view its definition. I certainly hope your organization uses some form of **source control** to hold its SQL that defines any of the database objects - refer to this source code to see what the view definition looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gettting the definition of sql objects you may use this query.

```
 GO
 exec sp_helptext <view_name>
 GO
```

If it encrypted by using ' *with encryption* ', then it is difficult to find the definition without having Administrative privilege.

Comment: It appears there is nothing I can do then, so I marked this as the answer.